# iReport (JasperReports) extra row issue

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I am getting an extra empty row between data when I am importing it from the database and formatting the report in Excel sheet.

**EDIT** (clarification from a comment): The output in Excel shows an extra blank row between records and and extra blank column between fields.

Comment: What do you mean `empty row between data`?

Comment: Suppose there are 2 columns in data base consisting some records when i am creating a report in IReports for the columns in database and corresponding records and importing it, M getting extra blank row and extra blank column between each field ..!

Answer (score 9):

- Add ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns`*** and ***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows`*** properties to report template.

***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns`*** - *Specifies whether the empty spacer columns should be removed or not.*

***`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows`*** - *Specifies whether the empty spacer rows should be removed or not.*

The sample:

```xml
<jasperReport ...>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
```

The information about configuration properties is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns).

- You can set ***isRemoveLineWhenBlank*** and ***isBlankWhenNull*** for *textField* element for hiding blank row.

The sample how to remove the whole line if the current *textField* is empty:

```xml
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

- Another assumption is to change the height of all *textField* (or/and *staticText*) elements in the *Band*.

In case this design:

[image: design with a space between textField and the band's boundary]

you will have a space between any two rows.

In case this design (*textField* height is equal to the *Band's* height):
[image: the textfield height is equal to the band's height]

the each line will be exactly under the other.

Comment: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns

Comment: send me ur email id i am not able to access any social networking site frm office location

Comment: It sounds like a design problem. Alex's advice should be good. Also refer to the FAQ: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/faq.html#FAQ9

Answer (score 3):

Every thing that Alex K states in his Dec 2 '11 answer is correct.  But a few other settings may be helpful.  These settings help when the text of the report stretches the detail band.

On every field in the detail band set:

positionType="Float"

stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"

Example:

```
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Prevent">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Transparent" x="372" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{your column name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

This  will force the all fields to be one height.   The float setting tells the field to minimize the distance between the previous and next row.  The RelativeToTallestObject setting tells all fields in the band to be the same height as the tallest field.  These two settings help eliminate 'empty space' which shows up as unwanted cells in Excel.