# How to avoid spaces between the data rows in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JasperReports* designer based on *Eclipse*) and I have defined four text fields representing four columns in a database table. But when I preview the report I have noted that each record will be displayed on a separate row (there will be a space between each row) which will look weird.

So how iIcan remove the spaces between the rows so that the table layout will be displayed normally?

Comment: You question looks similar the [iReport (JasperReports) extra row issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354126/ireport-jasperreports-extra-row-issue) question. You can view my answer on this post (especially 3rd solution)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that i should re-size the margin so that no empty space should be under the fields..